# MFG Date on replacement Lenovo ac adapter

Tags: lenovo-laptop

My Lenovo ac adapter needs to be replaced.  I found a replacement charger but the MFG Date and REV number of course is not the same. the MFG Date is usually 3 years or more older. Question: Does it make a difference in how old the MFG Date and Ver number is from the original charger?

Comment: If the product have the same characteristics *and*/*or* is said to be compatible by the manufacturer WHY would manufacturing date or revision/version, etc. matter?

Answer (score 1):

If the adapter is a genuine Lenovo Adapter and has the same voltage/amperage/wattage rating; and has the same FRU number, it will work just fine. The actual manufacturing date does not matter a lot as adapters do not age physically (at least not for about a decade).